# onSaveInstanceState is called, but savedInstanceState in onCreate method throws null

Tags: android, null, onsaveinstancestate, android-savedstate

put some serializable values to savedinstancestate, but savedInstanceState is null. onSaveInstanceState() is called with the log message, Code runs correcctly, but in onCreate method the null pointer is catched after restore the data and the saved state is null. the classes are correct. (serializable) is setted. i can't find the mistake. Thanks for help.

```
@override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.mb_activity);
            mBList = new ArrayList<MBClass>();
            mKList = new ArrayList<MKClass>();
            nAList = new ArrayList<AClass>();
            aList = new ArrayList<AClass>();
            try {
                mBList = (ArrayList<MBClass>) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("MBList");
                mKList = (ArrayList<MKClass>) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("MKList");
                aList = (ArrayList<AClass>) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("AList");
                nAList = (ArrayList<AClass>) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("NAList");

                Log.i("MB", "State geschrieben");

            } catch (NullPointerException ne) {
                //ne.printStackTrace();
                Log.i("MB", "State Null");
            }
    }
    @override    
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                savedInstanceState.putSerializable("MKList", (Serializable) mKList);
                savedInstanceState.putSerializable("MBList", (Serializable) mBList);
                savedInstanceState.putSerializable("NAList", (Serializable) nAList);
                savedInstanceState.putSerializable("AList", (Serializable) aList);
                super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
                Log.i("MB", "onSaveInstanceState");
            }
```

Comment: Did you make your classes serializable?

Comment: yes, the data is sended serially

Answer (score 0):

Replacing `Serializable` with `Parcelable` worked for me.

```
@Parcelize // this annotation is needed in Kotlin. Not Sure about Java
class DataClass implements Parcelable {
   //Data members
}
```

Comment: i will try, but this will take some time, have another problem